# Remove Android button without changing other buttons' layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

How I can disable offset of the button when calling removeView method?
When I pressed on the delete button

### I getting:

[image: default removeView method result]

### I need:

[image: what I need]

I can do this?
If I can, how.
if not, what I can do instead.

---

I need to just remove the button, because instead I add a new button in the same position.

### But when I remove the button using removeView for example removing Button0 my buttons Button1, Button2, Button3 shifted to the left. I need the buttons in their positions after the removal of Button0

Comment: button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

Answer (score 1):

use

```
button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try as:

```
private void removeView() {
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
int count = linearLayout.getChildCount();
if (count - 2 > 0) {
linearLayout.removeViewAt(count - 2);
}
}
```

**EDIT :** OR you can reove Button by id as from layout:

```
private void removeView() {
  LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
  Button btn_second= (Button) findViewById(R.id.second);
  linearLayout.removeView(btn_second);
}
```